# Fonts too small for high resolution screen for Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, display, display-resolution

I just installed Xubuntu on my new laptop. And fonts are too small on the high-resolution screen.

I checked Display panel in System settings, but I did not find any options to fix this. Does anyone have the similar issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with fonts in GTK-based applications (Thuderbird, Chromium etc).

I changed `.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
...
gtk-font-name="Oxygen-Sans Sans-Book 13"
...
```

There was 10 size previously.